# Java Regex for proper math operation

Tags: java, regex, string, math, calculator

This regex:

```
("[(\\d){1,} (*|+|-|/){1} (\\d){1,}]")
```

should catch all proper math operations,

(examples: "`3+4`","`3+3*6+2/3-6*434234+5`","`345345+2342/3/3/4-5`")

but wrong ones should not be catched.

(Examples:"`3+-2`","`+1`","`456+/5`","`3+4+5+`")

But it does not seem to catch any input at all.
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting that an unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash:

```
[(\\d){1,} (*|+|-|\/){1} (\\d){1,}]
                  ^ Escaped with backslash
```

**EDIT:**

In Java, you will need to use two  backslashes, since the  backslash is also an escape character in Java:

```
Matcher match = Pattern.compile("[(\\\\d){1,} (*|+|-|\\/){1} (\\\\d){1,}]").matcher("3+3*6+2/3-6*434234+5");
String s = "";
while (match.find())
    s += match.group() + "\n";
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Dont you need to double it in java ?

Comment: @Leyffda that is correct. This was just the raw regular expression. I'll clarify that a double backslash is needed.

Comment: ok it does not work with `\/` or `\\/`, but `\\\\/` works for some reason... thanks